# How to redirect %E2%80%8E and other weird links to right place?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

iv got quite a few good links that are out of my control but link to things like: http://mywebsite.com/somepage/%E2%80%8E when i want it to go to just http://mywebsite.com/somepage

often the %E2%80%8E is created if when some one is linking forgets to remove the /

other endings i get are....

```
/‎&
/&lrm;
& -----added to the end of the link... ie ..root/somepage&
```

Are there any htaccess rules i can apply to redirect things like this to the right place?

Any wordpress plugins that will help?

Thank you

(THIS IS BAD FOR SEO BECAUSE 404 PAGES ARE NOT COUNTED AND DO NOT PASS LINK JUICE)

I also dont in any of my urls have the character &

Answer (score 0):

Just place this rule **before all other rules** (right below `RewriteEngine On` line):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^/]+)/.*?[&%] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
```